# Multiply associative array by object where the keys match in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out the best way to multiply the values from an associative array by the values within an object where the keys match.

I have a JavaScript object with this structure:

```
Object {0: Object, 1: Object, 2: Object, 3: Object, 4: Object, 5: Object, 6: Object, 7: Object, 8: Object, 9: Object, 10: Object, 11: Object, 12: Object, 13: Object, 14: Object, 15: Object, 16: Object, 17: Object, 18: Object, 19: Object, 20: Object}
0: Object
 migforeign: 0.236575072366489
 migmunicip: 0.0560288755282917
 municipality: "Abrantes"
 popdent: 0.0297202684601973
 ppunit: 0.535590943544069
 qagedep: 0.396652635764728
 qfemale: 0.318397957136199
 qfhh: 0.563231479514655
 qforeign: 0.0569742908463333
 qrental: 0.60538345279747
 qurban: 0.507952069302096
 __proto__: Object
1: Object
 migforeign: 0.473038759939619
 migmunicip: 0.09940842629884
 municipality: "Alcanena"
 popdent: 0.0653282502099797
 ppunit: 0.72859029845259
 qagedep: 0.30339392964618
 qfemale: 0.306467891932506
 qfhh: 0.685415625421922
 qforeign: 0.27560826506132
 qrental: 0.626947992275036
 qurban: 0
 __proto__: Object
2: Object ...
```

I have an associative array:

```
var assosArray = [migforeign: 8.3, migmunicip: 4, popdent: 3, ppunit: 10, qagedep: 3, qfemale: 2.5, qfhh: 8.3, qforeign: 8.5, qrental: 2, qurban: 2]
```

I am trying to create a new object like this:

```
Object {0: Object, 1: Object, 2: Object, 3: Object, 4: Object, 5: Object, 6: Object, 7: Object, 8: Object, 9: Object, 10: Object, 11: Object, 12: Object, 13: Object, 14: Object, 15: Object, 16: Object, 17: Object, 18: Object, 19: Object, 20: Object}
0: Object
 migforeign: 1.96357310064186 // 0.236575072366489 * 8.3
 migmunicip: 0.22411550211317 // 0.0560288755282917 * 4
 municipality: "Abrantes"
 popdent: 0.08916080538059 // 0.0297202684601973 * 3
 ppunit: 5.35590943544069 // ...
 qagedep: 1.18995790729418
 qfemale: 0.7959948928405
 qfhh: 4.67482127997164
 qforeign: 0.48428147219383
 qrental: 1.21076690559494
 qurban: 1.01590413860419
 __proto__: Object
1: Object ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you need:

```
var o = {};
o[0] = { migforeign: 0.236575072366489, migmunicip: 0.0560288755282917 };
o[1] = { migforeign: 0.473038759939619,
        migmunicip: 0.09940842629884 }

var assoc = { migforeign: 8.3, migmunicip: 4 };

for(var p1 in o){
    for(var p2 in o[p1]){
        if(assoc.hasOwnProperty(p2)){
            o[p1][p2] *= assoc[p2];
        }
    }
}

console.log(o);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5azF6/

Answer (score 0):

Your array is not an array. It's an object with properties and values. This will *not* work:

```
var assosArray = [migforeign: 8.3, migmunicip: 4, popdent: 3, ppunit: 10, qagedep: 3, qfemale: 2.5, qfhh: 8.3, qforeign: 8.5, qrental: 2, qurban: 2]
```

This will work:

```
var assosArray = {
    migforeign: 8.3,
    migmunicip: 4,
    popdent: 3,
    ppunit: 10,
    qagedep: 3,
    qfemale: 2.5,
    qfhh: 8.3,
    qforeign: 8.5,
    qrental: 2,
    qurban: 2
};
```

You can loop your object like this:

```
var myNewObj = {};
for (prop in obj) {
    if ( assosArray[prop] ) {
        myNewObj[prop] = assosArray[prop] * obj[prop];
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/B3E3E/).

Take a look at your console.

Answer (score 0):

Is that "associative array" of yours even valid syntax? I don't think so - just make it an object (which, in JavaScript, is a dictionary).

Then you could just do something like:

```
for (var i = 0; values.length; ++i) {
    for (var key in assosArray) {
        if (assosArray.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            values[i][key] *= assosArray[key];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll make it an object, no problem, thx, your right the syntax is off, my bad